# Failed to insert into HDFS from HIVE table using INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY

Tags: sql, join, hadoop, hive, hiveql

My primary need is to load a file in HDFS from HIVE using INSERT OVERWRITE uery. In this query I am trying to join 3 hive tables. Below is the query:

```
select * FROM 
    AGG_CUSTOMER_EXPSR_DRV_HIVE DRV 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    AGG_CUSTOMER_EXPSR_SRC_HIVE SRC 
ON 
    (SRC.CUSTOMER_ID = DRV.CUSTOMER_ID) 
    AND (SRC.AGGREGATION_LEVEL_CD = DRV.AGGREGATION_LEVEL_CD) 
    AND (SRC.PRODUCT_GROUP_CD = DRV.PRODUCT_GROUP_CD) AND (SRC.SRC_SYS_CD = DRV.SRC_SYS_CD) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ALTERNATE_IP_HIVE AIP1 
ON 
    (DRV.DERIVED_CUSTOMER_ID = AIP1.IP_ID) AND (AIP1.IP_TYPE_CD IN (1, 4)) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ALTERNATE_IP_HIVE AIP3 
ON 
    (SRC.FINANCIAL_RPTNG_UNIT_ID = AIP3.IP_ID) AND (AIP3.IP_TYPE_CD = 3) 
WHERE EXCLUDE_IND ='N';
```

But I am getting error as below:
`-sh: syntax error near unexpected token`(`

Can someone please help me in finding out the issue?

Note: I have removed the fields in SELECT clause.

Answer (score 0):

if you have created a table in hive with the number of result fields from the above sql then you can simply do as

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE <database_name.your_created_table_name> SELECT * FROM 
    AGG_CUSTOMER_EXPSR_DRV_HIVE DRV 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    AGG_CUSTOMER_EXPSR_SRC_HIVE SRC 
ON 
    (SRC.CUSTOMER_ID = DRV.CUSTOMER_ID) 
    AND (SRC.AGGREGATION_LEVEL_CD = DRV.AGGREGATION_LEVEL_CD) 
    AND (SRC.PRODUCT_GROUP_CD = DRV.PRODUCT_GROUP_CD) AND (SRC.SRC_SYS_CD = DRV.SRC_SYS_CD) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ALTERNATE_IP_HIVE AIP1 
ON 
    (DRV.DERIVED_CUSTOMER_ID = AIP1.IP_ID) AND (AIP1.IP_TYPE_CD IN (1, 4)) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ALTERNATE_IP_HIVE AIP3 
ON 
    (SRC.FINANCIAL_RPTNG_UNIT_ID = AIP3.IP_ID) AND (AIP3.IP_TYPE_CD = 3) 
WHERE EXCLUDE_IND ='N';
```

from SELECT it is your query. You can check [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-SELECTSandFILTERS) URL for more help on hiveql

Comment: Sorry.. My bad.. I tried running the INSERT OVERWRITE query in HIVE command promt and now its working fine. But Below CASE statement is causing an issue:

Comment: CASE WHEN (DRV.AGGREGATION_LEVEL_CD = 1) THEN 
  CASE WHEN (SUBSTR(AIP1.SRC_SYS_UNIQUE_KEY_TXT, 1, (INSTR(AIP1.SRC_SYS_UNIQUE_KEY_TXT, '~', 1, 1) - 1)) NOTNULL) 
    THEN SUBSTR(AIP1.SRC_SYS_UNIQUE_KEY_TXT, 1, (INSTR(AIP1.SRC_SYS_UNIQUE_KEY_TXT, '~', 1, 1) - 1)) 

FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10015]: Line 1:1125 Arguments length mismatch '1': The function INSTR accepts exactly 2 arguments.
   WHEN ('') THEN '' ELSE NULL END ELSE '' END AS OVERRIDE_FAMILY_CUSTOMER_SRC_SYS_CD,

Comment: can you share your complete query and also pl specify what issue you are getting

Comment: Actually my issue was that I was not able to use JOIN while importing a table from HIVE into HDFS through INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY. The query i used in above INSERT has INSTR, SUBSTR, NOT NULL and the issue was with the INSTR syntax. I was not aware of the INSTR syntax difference between SQL and HIVE-QL.
Now its working fine.

Comment: glad you got it working. if possible just edit your question and put your solution with comments, so in case if anybody checks this post, it gets helpful to them.

Comment: in normal SQL we can pass 2,3 arguments in INSTR but in HIVE-QL we can pass only 2 arguments. Anything more than that will throw an error.
instr(string str, string substr) -->> Returns the position of the first occurrence of substr in str 
locate(string substr, string str[,int pos]) -->> Returns the position of the first occurrence of substr in str after position pos